# Visual Studio 2015 and FetchXML

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm-2015

Does anybody know a way to get Visual Studio 2015 to work with MS CRM FetchXML connections when doing SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but there is no easy and supported way of doing it. Supported configurations are:
The following components are required:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 
-- OR --
Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server Data Tools

You can see this information here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45013

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, but was hoping maybe someone out there would have found a way to make this work. Microsoft really needs to be pushing this stuff up to their newest versions of VS.

Comment: I'm still not seeing a solution for this. From what I've gathered it still only works with 2012. If someone has this working in 2015 please let me know and ill keep working on it.